# Selenium IDE: Check if checkbox is ticked, if not then check

Tags: selenium-ide

I seem to be looking in the wrong direction so perhaps someone can help me.

In my testcase i need to have 1 specific checkbox 'on' at all times, i need some kind of if/else loop imo but can't figure it out. Can someone come to the rescue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**A simple if statement works like given above, you could try yourself.**

If you change the target value to `true` for *`if command`* then the output will be `Passed` and if you keep it as `false`, the output will be `fail`.

**Coming to your question**

if you want to verify whether a checkbox is selected. You can use the `verify checked` command.

But, these commands do not have any return value and so, cannot be used for conditional statements.

For controlling the flow according to checkbox status, you can use execute script command to verify the 'checked' property of the element:

**Add the below command in IDE:**

```
command: execute script
Target : return (document.querySelectorAll('[name="selected(1234)"]'))[0].checked
value: test
```

**Note:** queryselector is the function to identify an element using CSS locator, full list of supported element locators  could be found at :

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Note that few locators return arrays and few returns single element. You should handle it accordingly. for instance, query selector returns an array of 1 element so I took [0] the first element.

**Final code would look like:**

[image]

**.side file:**

Just copy the below code and save it as `test.side` file. Now open it in IDE and run it and see how the control flow works.

```
{
  "id": "e775f634-710f-41a4-9d86-ed26d93f5f78",
  "version": "2.0",
  "name": "sdad",
  "url": "http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "81f96aae-1436-4766-9005-f868d5350de4",
    "name": "sd",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "50ff0f41-4ec0-41fa-992f-d2ec9d4f6381",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "/chapter1",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "a8a9e9b1-1d61-49a3-ab18-5e6598e5c1ed",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "setWindowSize",
      "target": "1897x1040",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "408fc4ff-6bbd-4c42-b8d3-f09ca43a5b45",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "select",
      "target": "id=selecttype",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "label=Selenium Core"
    }, {
      "id": "163049da-7205-440d-923c-51356cc5f22b",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "//click",
      "target": "name=selected(1234)",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "f6f8739c-86c6-40ea-a235-eeb8c7c2f374",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "executeScript",
      "target": "return (document.querySelectorAll('[name=\"selected(1234)\"]'))[0].checked",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "test"
    }, {
      "id": "d7952432-7499-4173-b7bd-e09663163708",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "${test}",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "0e83238a-ec38-4247-b1e6-485bd81c680a",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "if",
      "target": "${test}",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "6f832f5c-31df-41f1-a399-c7348095f614",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "Passed",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "6d2f22db-11b5-43b8-a56e-1ef7991fd503",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "else",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "c77edb7b-22df-4507-91bc-f03c7e71bddb",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "fail",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "30c78100-ab95-4382-8ae2-b98ee8d60826",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "end",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }]
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "cb4118db-162f-4ca5-a002-ceb87733dbba",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": ["81f96aae-1436-4766-9005-f868d5350de4"]
  }],
  "urls": ["http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

**Final code looks like:**

[image]

Now you can see how test flow changes by running the test with step 4 enabled and then disabled

Comment: I already noticed the related question but that didn't seem to be an answer for my problem. Thanks @PDHide for the answer but i'm still not sure how it applies to my issue. With the given information, could you type up the steps I would need in my code so I can see what you mean? 
Would help a lot, big thanks upfront !

Comment: Figured it out, the Javascrypt on the side was new for me but it works great now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Simon123 could you accept by clicking the tick sign